# essay checking recommendations

Tags: discussion

i was practicing for my English exam next which is to be conducted next month but i don't  have any idea where can I get suggestions on the essay. I only need to know if my essay sounds interesting not much issue about the grammar can any one help me out with any website which does help in this?

Comment: We have no idea either. All English exams are different, and all essay writing exams are graded by somebody. You might know who; we don't. And we don't know what you've been taught or what country you're in or what languages you speak, either. So we really can't help you much. Talk to your teachers.